# No .onion sites load

Tags: onion-services

I cannot connect to any .onion sites. I have used both duckduckgo's onion link as well as the torproject's onion link as tests.

I have read every thread and post related to this issue I can find, the only things any of them mention is to either reinstall Tor, which I have done several times, including the latest alpha release, or that it may be a clock issue, I have changed the time one hour back and one hour forward.

None of these things have fixed the issue.

The only things I can find on the net about this are a couple of reddit, stackoverflow and yahoo answers threads. None shed any real light or offer solutions.

Any help is appreciated, even just some links to information with some depth.

Please do not mark this post as a duplicate. it is an issue that needs attention not just for myself but for the many people who must be having this problem.

Log info

```
8/7/2015 13:17:55 PM.774 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
8/7/2015 13:17:56 PM.272 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
8/7/2015 13:17:57 PM.366 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
8/7/2015 13:17:57 PM.366 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
8/7/2015 13:17:58 PM.500 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
8/7/2015 13:17:58 PM.910 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
8/7/2015 13:20:17 PM.813 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
8/7/2015 13:22:33 PM.553 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
8/7/2015 13:22:55 PM.562 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
8/7/2015 13:23:23 PM.891 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
8/7/2015 13:23:56 PM.425 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
8/7/2015 13:24:19 PM.235 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
8/7/2015 13:24:55 PM.793 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
8/7/2015 13:25:48 PM.365 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
8/7/2015 13:45:31 PM.124 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later).
```

I tried many more .onion sites than are indicated in this log. Sites that should be available, like Tor's own .onion and duckduckgo's. Can it be they are all unavailable?

Is there a way to test for sure whether it is me or the browser?

Comment: Have a look at the "[Tor isn't working](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#DoesntWork)" suggestions on the Tor FAQ. It's possible your ISP is blocking connections to Tor, in which case you'd need to use a bridge. One of the suggestions on the FAQ is to check the logs... (which are probably a minimum requirement for anyone being able to help.)

Comment: Tor is working fine for regular sites, it's the .onion sites that are not being connected too. i'll edit my post to add the log info.

Comment: What are the URLs you have for Tor and DuckDuckGo? Try the Facebook .onion address, which is the one I usually use for testing (Facebook is huge, and they almost certainly host their own hidden services) - https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/ (I've just checked - it works for me).

Comment: thanks for the link Richard. it is something with my machine. i just installed tor on another machine on my home network and the facebook link worked. so it has something to do with my computer. i have a malwarebytes trial that has live protection but i shut that down through task manager. i don't have any other AV installed. and it's not the router obviously, but at least know now the problem lies with this one computer. could it be windows defender somehow?

Comment: If Tor works fine for non-onion sites, then I can't see that Windows Defender would be the problem. Just to confirm, you also can't access the Facebook onion page from the initial computer?

Comment: i turned off defender live protection and scheduled scanning but still no joy. that's correct. i cannot access the facebook onion page from the initial computer, but i can access it from a second computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i got it working. not sure how to explain this clearly but it had to do with the computer clock. on the computer it did work on, the clock had a central time zone. the computer it didn't work on, had a mountain time zone, although both clocks showed the right time because i had previously adjust it by one hour manually when booted the computer for the very first time.

so then i changed the mountain time zone to central, but then the clock was off by one hour, i tried tor that way but still no good. so i adjusted it manually to show the right time with the central time zone. but .onion sites still do not load.

so i looked at the clock settings again and saw it was synchronized to a internet time server. i unchecked the option and the .onion site loaded.

i wish i could explain it more concisely but i hope this can still help someone else.

thank you to Richard Horrocks for helping and Stig Atle Steffensen for editing my log info to make it more readable.

Comment: I fixed by setting my system timezone to UTC.